# Junit test cases are not running when i do mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, junit

[image]I have written a spring boot application. I have written Junit test cases as well for that. When i run `mvn clean install` command, test cases are not running as part of that mvn build. But when i just right click and run as Junit test case all my test cases execute. I believe there is some configuration error.
Am using spring-boot, maven as build and Eclipse ide.

My test class name is TestService.java and it is in src/test folder

```
public class TestService {

    JsonUtil jsonUtil;
    String jsonString;
    @Before
    public void setData() {
        jsonString = "{\"id\":\"one\"}";
        jsonUtil = new JsonUtil(new ObjectMapper());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStringAsJson() {

        JsonNode node = jsonUtil.getStringAsJson(jsonString);
        Assert.assertEquals("one", node.get("id").textValue());
    }

}
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
  <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>xyz</name>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- dependency versions -->
        <com.google.guava.guava.version>22.0</com.google.guava.guava.version>
        <io.springfox.springfox-swagger2>2.7.0</io.springfox.springfox-swagger2>
        <io.springfox.springfox-swagger-ui>2.7.0</io.springfox.springfox-swagger-ui>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- For default Spring Boot utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For testing possibility -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For all mvc and web functions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring security related dependencies 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- Default persistence functions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- In-Memory DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java Utilities from google -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${com.google.guava.guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Include swagger for API description -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${io.springfox.springfox-swagger2}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Include swagger for API description UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${io.springfox.springfox-swagger-ui}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Common libraries  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Maven output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xyz 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ xyz ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\rk\Documents\WS\xyz\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ xyz ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ xyz ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 17 source files to C:\Users\rk\Documents\WS\xyz\target\classes
[WARNING] /C:/Users/rk/Documents/WS/xyz/src/main/java/com/weather/xyzTestApplication.java: C:\Users\rk\Documents\WS\xyz\src\main\java\com\weather\xyzTestApplication.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/rk/Documents/WS/xyz/src/main/java/com/weather/xyzTestApplication.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ xyz ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ xyz ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\rk\Documents\WS\xyz\target\test-classes
[WARNING] /C:/Users/rk/Documents/WS/xyz/src/test/java/com/weather/controller/TestxyzController.java: C:\Users\rk\Documents\WS\xyz\src\test\java\com\weather\controller\TestxyzController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/rk/Documents/WS/xyz/src/test/java/com/weather/controller/TestxyzController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ xyz ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ xyz ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\rk\Documents\WS\xyz\target\xyz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ xyz ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ xyz ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\rk\Documents\WS\xyz\target\xyz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\rk\.m2\repository\com\weather\xyz\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\xyz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\rk\Documents\WS\xyz\pom.xml to C:\Users\rk\.m2\repository\com\weather\xyz\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\xyz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.643 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-24T22:44:24+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/248M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the path to TestService.java relative to your project root? Is it `src/test/TestService.java` or is it `src/test/java/com/foo/bar/TestService.java`

Comment: it is \src\test\java\com\...\TestService.java

Comment: Does running the given command below execute the test cases. If yes, then please share your pom.xml.         "mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=false"

Comment: The output from `tree` or a similar view of your project structure would help too. Ensure that your project conforms to the standard directory layout: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: running clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=false also didn't run the test

Comment: updated with project structure

Comment: What is the maven build output ?

Comment: is your test src folder added in build path?

Comment: Updated with maven build output

Comment: @Nutan it is in build path

Comment: are you using mockito? have you added any annotation on TestService, if any can you mention  that

Comment: I don't know the spring dependencies by heart, but is JUnit part of any spring dependency? I ask, because I don't see any JUnit dependency in your pom.xml.

Comment: spring-boot-starter-test is enough actually for junits in spring boot application

Comment: it should be. Because i get all Junit classes to work with. Another thing i have missed is <packaging>jar</packaging>. Even after adding that not working

Comment: if you are using mockito try using this annotation on your test service class: @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
Also can you try and rename the test class to ServiceTest.java, check if it works for *Test.java format

Comment: Am using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class). Not working

Comment: Well well well. Finally God shown some mercy. I had to upgrade <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent> . I dont know what changed by upgrading version. But now i can see it run test case during build. I was comparing with some other project and this was the change

Comment: that shouldn't have been the problem.

Comment: I will revert the version and confirm again

Answer (score 1):

Check pom.xml go to 'Effective POM' view.
Check the value for  tag under . It seems like it is not pointing to the proper location. You may override the property in pom.xml if it is pointing to a different location.

Comment: I would recommend that OP move the code to the expected, standard location instead of changing the POM. You can change the location, but using the standard maven tree is generally better since there are fewer customizations to track and manage.

Comment: <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\rk\Documents\xyz\abc\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
<testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\rk\Documents\xyz\abc\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>  this looks correct

Comment: this all configuration looks correct only. Try disabling maven behavior and enabling it again(if using eclipse).

Comment: I did this as well. No luck :(

Comment: Try running build in debug mode and check what happens in surefire plugin. Also does mvn test executes the test cases?

Answer (score 0):

How would you have created the pom through spring initializer or manually? Most likely build path issue causing plugin not to execute. Can you check which version is being used once run through eclipse later verify through mvn dependency: tree just to know the same version is also available from cmd.